# Parallax mechanics

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I would play a [Brago, King Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrago%2c%20King%20Eternal%5d) EDH deck but it is not clear in my mind how does the parallax cards work. I thought that I could remove only a fade counter each turn but googling I read different things: seems that people remove more than one land/creature each turn without using extra cards like [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d). So they are able to exile up to 4 card each turn. How does parallax mechanics work? Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: I am honestly not sure how they would work with Brago either, since Brago's flicker ability is sorcery speed, and any flicker that would reset them would have to be done in response to the triggers from removing the counters. Remove 4 counters - 4 exile abilities on stack, 1 counter left, flicker Parallax, parallax tries to return all cards exiled (none) then comes back with 5 new counters, 4 exile triggers resolve. Also worth noting you'd only gt 4 cards the first turn you play it, turns after you'd get 3, since one of the fade counters would have been faded off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "parallax cards" you are almost certainly [Parallax Tide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bParallax%20Tide%5d) and [Parallax Wave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bParallax%20Wave%5d). These cards have Fading, but these cards also have the additional mechanic that allows you to remove an additional fade counter whenever you want to get a certain effect. In normal play, this creates a tradeoff, where you can activate the ability more times, but that results in the lands or creatures you exile returning sooner.

However, with certain other cards, you can abuse effect timing and stacking to either exile lands or creatures permanently, or flicker creatures whenever you want. To exile things permanently, you can activate the ability targeting what you want to get rid of, then with all of those abilities on the stack, cast a card like [Flicker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlicker%5d). This will cause the parallax card's last ability to trigger before anything gets exiled, so when those cards do get exiled they will never return. In addition, if you allow any of those abilities to resolve before casting Flicker, those exiled cards will return, so you can also effectively use it to flicker multiple lands or creatures.

In addition, if you have Parallax Wave with [Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOpalescence%5d), Parallax Wave will be a creature, so you can use its own ability to exile itself, then the last ability will trigger and it will return itself. This will allow you to effectively use its own ability as a makeshift Flicker, and do the previously described process repeatedly.

Comment: How does this work when considering the speed of the abilities, you'd have to activate the flicker ability while the exile abilities from parallax cards are on the stack, but Brago is a triggered flicker which goes on stack due to damage, which no longer uses the stack, therefore is effectively sorcery speed (empty stack)

Comment: You're right that the specific interaction to permanently exile stuff doesn't work with Brago. But I mentioned allowing the abilities to resolve before the Flicker effect to flicker stuff, which does work with Brago. It can be kind of redundant with Brago, but you can use it with Parallax Tide to flicker lands.

Comment: Then Parallax wave is redundant here. Are there any ways to actually do a permanent exile with this, just did a quick gatherer search for instants that flicker, but none flicker enchantments, almost all creatures, and a few artifact and land?

Comment: I linked to the card Flicker in my answer, which does exactly that.

Comment: Except Flicker is a sorcery, so you can't use it in response to the Parallax abilities. It has similar timing issues to Brago.

Comment: Ghostly Flicker or Momentary Blink would do the trick. (I don't know how to post links apparently lol)

Comment: @RubixRechvin [Ghostly Flicker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240101) cannot target Enchantments, [Momentary Blink](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425841) can only target creatures. Parallax Tide and Parallax Wave are both enchantments. Like I was saying there does not seem to be an instant source of flicker for enchantments, without giving your spells flash (IE [Layline of Anticipation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205008))